# C# get text content inside axShockwaveFlash1?

Tags: c#, flash, bots, axshockwaveflash

I loaded a game online to axShockwaveFlash1 winform.

[code inside flash running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X33fM.png)

[image: code]

Have any way to get name and level of my character from C#?

[inside game here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shoao.jpg)

[image: inside game]

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO. Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please explain what is your goal, what is your problem, and your question, share some code to help use help you.
Do not post print screens of code.. use the editor formatting and use real code.

Comment: Sorry! my topic's edit button not found. This game online call My app is thirth party. Code AS3 print screen: I found swf file in IE cache, decode and print it. Print screen 2nd is my app loaded this game to axShockwaveFlash1. name property and level property in picture 1,  I tip them in picture 2. My ask: How to I get values of name and level to show in my app: this.Text = name + " level: "+ level;

Comment: @NamPT just use this link (the `edit` button goes to this page) : **https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46566626/edit**. About _"decode and print it."_ should be _decode and then copy/paste that code text_. Usually you code the Flash app to give this information (via a Flash function) then allow access to same function using `External Interface`. If you did not design the Flash app to send out such info, it won't be possible to get it.